# bind email containing apostrophes to angular model

Tags: angularjs, html, validation

I have an input type email that I validate against my own custom regular expression. It in turn is bound to an angular model something like:

js

```
$scope.user = {};
```

html

```
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" />
```

I would like for the email to allow apostrophes but the email doesn't bind to the model unless it passes the built in html5 validation. I'd like to override or switch off this validation since I have my own custom regex in place.

I've tried adding the novalidate tag to the form wrapper and also adding a pattern to the input but not getting anywhere. Please see jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19499/

Any ideas greatly appreciated

C

EDIT: The reason I'm not using type="text" is because I want the email keyboard set to be there when accessing from mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Angular do not support the `apostrophe(')` in email Id , if need to valid the apostrophe in angular, need to change in angular file regular expr

```
(/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/)
```

to

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/.
```

It will Work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a regex for validation, you could set the type of the input tag to "text" so that then it would not do any validation and then the regex you have already created could be used to do the validation you want. Also, this will allow you to change the validation method if you ever decide to change how you want validation to work.

Here's the tag:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.email" />
```

Comment: Then perhaps do use type="text", but you could add a little button next to the field with the "@" symbol. This is more an issue with UX, and there are other, more efficient ways around this problem than what you are attempting to do, which while is admirable and thoughtful to your users, is also a little cumbersome on your part. Consider my alternative solution; it may serve you well.

Comment: Hope I don't seem to stubborn; I only intend to stimulate thought and creativity.